# Bootstrap datepicker showing no error but not working as well

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="span2"></div>
        <div class="span3">
                <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="dpd1" class="form-control" name="from_date" placeholder="Reserve From">
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
                <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="dpd2" class="form-control" name="to_date" placeholder="Reserve Upto">
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span2">
                <div class="">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Click to reserve
                        </button>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I have included these js files in my PHP file

```
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>        
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/date.js"></script>
```

Here is my `date.js` file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dpd1').datepicker({
          onRender: function() {

            }
    });
});
```

I don't understand where is the problem. Can u guys please suggest me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you looked at the console to make sure that you're loading all of the libraries?

Answer (score 2):

try to recheck path-to-your-js or use live path available
Such as:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can try as follows, if that work move further function with your JavaScript-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dpd1').datepicker();
});
```

or,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#dpd1').datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> $(document).ready(function() {
>    $('#dpd1').datepicker();
>         });

I think you missed CSS files and images. There is no error in your code.